# Info windows with tabs content

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

i am doing Fusion Tables Layer with tabbed info window using jQuery UI
One of the tab is "ProductDesc" which I have many line desc only in one column

**I would like it display in such way:**

- New, custom-installed two-inch blinds throughout
- New, front-load washers and dryers
- New interior wood mouldings and trim
- Shower enclosures in selected units
- New roofs on all residential buildings
- New air conditioners and air handlers
- New indoor plumbing
- New electrical wiring throughout with new refrigeration lines in each kitchen
- New, double-insulated windows

**But when it load the maps at browser, it look messy**

*New, custom-installed two-inch blinds throughout * New, front-load washers and dryers *  New interior wood mouldings and trim * Shower enclosures in selected units * New roofs on all residential buildings * New air conditioners and air handlers * New indoor plumbing * New electrical wiring throughout with new refrigeration lines in e ach kitchen * New, double-insulated windows

How to make it nice, it is impossible i break to many column for each line of desc. Thanks

Comment: What data is stored in the table?  Can you provide a link or a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem and/or the table ID?  It really sounds like you just need to format it with HTML.

Comment: Dear geocodezip,
you are right, pls refer Table ID 5288402.
pls guide how to format it with HTML. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want an [unordered list](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) in HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
</ul>
```

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S693735w-hy